# Is there Hodge isomorphism between Dolbeault and Harmonic on noncompact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

As is well known , Hodge theorem tells us

Let $(X, g)$ be a **compact** hermitian manifold. Then the canoni.
cal projection $\mathcal{H}_{\bar{\partial}}^{p, q}(X, g) \rightarrow H^{p, q}(X)$ is an isomorphism.
i.e., Dolbeault cohomology groups is isomorphic with the corresponding harmonic spaces.

**My question is:**

1) Is there the Hodge decomposition on noncompact manifolds?

2) Are Dolbeault cohomology groups  isomorphic with the corresponding harmonic spaces.
?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11764